# what does the 'addDecl' option do in pear - XML_Serialize

Tags: php, xml-serialization, pear

I am looking at the [examples](https://78.129.214.25/manual/en/package.xml.xml-serializer.xml-serializer.examples.php) given at the XML_Serialize pear plugin manual.

I can't figure out what the option 'addDecl' does in this plugin.

What does this do?

I can't seem to find it in their [documentation](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/docs)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a (confident) guess, it'll be the XML Declaration at the start of the document

i.e.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Answer (score 0):

Reading the source that's exactly what it does - I've raised this as a bug in their documentation.